Command 'cdh' not found appearing at the top of CL when opened
I am new to Ubuntu, and I am using the latest version. Initially, I wanted to create an alias, using:
alias cdh='cd /home/[My name]/'

This was done since I wanted to download video files to a different hard drive than my M.2., and convert them to a different format. However, I ran into the error of the cd not working. I then reset the paths with unaliasing cdh, and then changing the directory using
~$ cd /

so that it would point to the root. However, now every time I open the Command Line, I get:
Command 'cdh' not found, did you mean:
  command 'cdb' from deb tinycdb (0.78build3)
  command 'cdp' from deb irpas (0.10-9)
  command 'cdw' from deb cdw (0.8.1-2)
  command 'cdo' from deb cdo (2.0.4-1)
  command 'dch' from deb devscripts (2.22.1ubuntu1)
  command 'cde' from deb cde (0.1+git9-g551e54d-1.2)
  command 'dh' from deb debhelper (13.6ubuntu1)
  command 'csh' from deb csh (20110502-7)
  command 'csh' from deb tcsh (6.21.00-1.1)
  command 'cph' from deb conda-package-handling (1.7.3-2build1)
  command 'cdi' from deb cdo (2.0.4-1)
  command 'cd5' from deb cd5 (0.1-4)
Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
bash: cd: too many arguments

This does not seem to affect anything though, as I went through and checked stuff like brew and the CLI I installed to convert things, but I am concerned that it is sending those messages when just opening the command line. If there is further detail I need to add to this question, I am willing to do so.
Please go easy on me, again I am completely new to this stuff and I just wanted to set up some video converting CLI in Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS. Thank you!
EDIT 1:
It is defined in the ~/.bashrc, as even on start up after a fresh reset the error still appears at the top.

Aliases are only defined for the current shell session, so if you did not add the alias to your shell's startup files (~/.bashrc), it would not be defined in any new sessions. It is not clear where you defined the alias, or where it is being used, so this may not be a correct guess as to what the issue might be. Also, to cd to your home directory, just use cd without any arguments.

Abandon cdh. A simple cd (no parameter) will return you to $HOME

Related: for any recent Ubuntu (or Linux for that matter), the environment variable HOME is set to "/home/[username]".  So in cases where it makes sense (ie. not cd this one :-), you can use $HOME to refer to your home directory.
